# problem with simpleXMLElement

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Here is my PHP code

```
$xml= new SimpleXmlElement($rawxml);
    foreach($xml->children()->children() AS $key){
        $id = $xml->{"id"};
        $name = $xml->{"screen_name"};
        $profimg = $xml->{"profile_image_url"};
        echo "$id, $name, $profimg";
    }
$next = $xml->{"next_link"};
echo "index.php?".$next;
```

Here is the structure of my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <users_list>
        <users type="array">
            <user>
              <id>44444</id>
              <screen_name>Some Name</screen_name>
              <profile_image_url>http://www.website.com/picture.jpg</profile_image_url>
            </user>
            <user>
              <id>555</id>
              <screen_name>Bob</screen_name>
              <profile_image_url>http://www.website.com/picture2.jpg</profile_image_url>
            </user>
            <user>
              <id>666666</id>
              <screen_name>Frank</screen_name>
              <profile_image_url>http://www.website.com/picture3.jpg</profile_image_url>
            </user>
        </users>
        <next_link>44444</next_link>
    </users_list>
```

Im trying to assign the values of the  field to variables and then echo them. Then at the bottom echo the nextlink.

I dont get any errors, but it just shows the first  field over and over, and doesnt output the nextlink.

Comment: This is the XML that im trying to handle.
http://twitter.com/statuses/followers/barackobama.xml?cursor=-1

Comment: Is that me or you've posted that question 3 times over with different wordings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re using `$key` in the `foreach` expression but `$xml` inside the `foreach` body.

I would also prefer an [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath) expression rather than your *children of the children of the root* way:

```
foreach ($xml->xpath('/users_list/users/user') as $user) {
    $id = $user->id;
    $name = $user->screen_name;
    $profimg = $user->profile_image_url;
    echo "$id, $name, $profimg";
}
```

Comment: this is returning no errors, but no data as well, just blank.

Comment: @Patrick: Well, it works for me. Did you try my code in substitution of yours or in addition to yours?

Comment: @Patrick: I just put the XML code in `$rawxml = '…';`, created a new SimpleXML object like you did and then put my suggested `foreach` after that and it worked like a charm.